# Query based on Checkboxes

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm working on a program that will query a personal movie database.
The wrinkle in the plan is selecting genres.
For instance, let's say I have 3 checkboxes Action, Adventure and Comedy.
A movie could fall into one genre or multiple genres.
A movie could be an Action OR an Action/comedy.

The code snippet below is what I started with...but does not accommodate all the variations.  The Fill_Grid function populates a dataGridView.  It works if the movie has one genre or if the user selects exactly the same genres that a movie has in the database.
What needs to happen is if a movie is an Action Comedy it should show up if the user selects only Action or only comedy OR Action and Comedy.

Please ask questions if this does not make sense.

Thanks in advance,
-J

```
       string str_SQL = "SELECT Name, File, Action, Fantasy, Horror, Thriller, Adventure, Animation, Comedy, Crime, Documentary, Drama, Family, Games, Mystery, Romance, SciFi, War FROM tbl_Main WHERE Action = " + chk_Action.Checked +
            " AND Fantasy = " + chk_Adv.Checked +
            " AND Horror = " + chk_Hor.Checked +
            " AND Thriller = " + chk_Thrill.Checked +
            " AND Adventure = " + chk_Adv.Checked +
            " AND Animation = " + chk_Anim.Checked +
            " AND Comedy = " + chk_Com.Checked +
            " AND Crime = " + chk_Crime.Checked +
            " AND Documentary = " + chk_Doc.Checked +
            " AND Drama = " + chk_Drama.Checked +
            " AND Family = " + chk_Fam.Checked +
            " AND Games = " + chk_Game.Checked +
            " AND Mystery = " + chk_Mys.Checked +
            " AND Romance = " + chk_Rom.Checked +
            " AND SciFi = " + chk_Sci.Checked +
            " AND War = " + chk_War.Checked + ";";

            Fill_Grid(str_SQL);
```

Comment: You should always use [_parameterized queries_](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) This kind of codes is open for an [_SQL Injection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @Tom - because if you have an Action Comedy, and you check Action and Romance, it will still be returned.

Comment: I am the first to point out to newcomers the perils of SQL Injection, but in this case I can't see how this could happen

Comment: So let me understand. A film is market as Action + Comedy. The user selects just Comedy (OK), the user selects Action AND Drama (OK), the user select Drama AND Mistery (Not OK)? (Where OK means the query should find the film)

Comment: If a movie is in Action and Comedy it should show up in three genres, Action, Comedy and Action/Comedy.  If a user selects Action/Drama, the movie should not show up because it is not Action and Drama, it is Action and Comedy

Comment: Would it be possible to loop through each check box on the form and ONLY add those selections that have been checked into the query?  This might alleviate the problem of a movie falling into multiple genres and not having the program drop those movies that are not checked.

Comment: The real problem here is that you're starting with a totally de-normalized table structure. This is very easy of you have a `Genres` table with a many-to-many relationship to the `Movies` table. With the structure you have here whenever you think of a new genre you're going to need to add a column to your table, that table is going to get huge and have lots of empty columns that mean nothing to most records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet below works.  Thank you all for your input, you got me headed in the right direction

```
string str_Checkboxes="";
string str_SQL = "SELECT Name, File, Action, Fantasy, Horror, Thriller, Adventure, Animation, Comedy, Crime, Documentary, Drama, Family, Games, Mystery, Romance, SciFi, War FROM tbl_Main WHERE ";

//Loop through each control on the form, we are looking for checkboxes
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
 {
  if(c is CheckBox)
    {
      if (((CheckBox)c).Checked)
        {
         //Bypass putting AND at the beginning of str_Checkboxes
         if(str_Checkboxes != "")
           str_Checkboxes+=" AND ";
         //Checkbox text is the same as the field name in the database
           str_Checkboxes += (((CheckBox)c).Text) + " = True";
        }
     }
   }
//build the SQL
str_SQL += str_Checkboxes + ";"; 
//Fill the grid
Fill_Grid(str_SQL);
```

Answer (score 3):

See if the checkbox is checked first.  Then, add it to the query.

```
if (chk_Adv.Checked == true) {
   str_SQL = str_SQL+" AND Fantasy = 1"
}
```

Comment: The program is a standalone.
Replacing all AND's with OR's does not work.  It will return all of the data regardless of what has been selected.  I'm not familiar with parameterized queries unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if all the columns datatype is `bit` in sql:

```
string str_SQL = "SELECT Name, File, Action, Fantasy, Horror, Thriller, Adventure, Animation, Comedy, Crime, Documentary, Drama, Family, Games, Mystery, Romance, SciFi, War FROM tbl_Main WHERE Action = " + chk_Action.Checked +
" AND Fantasy = " + chk_Adv.Checked?-1 :0 +
" AND Horror = " + chk_Hor.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Thriller = " + chk_Thrill.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Adventure = " + chk_Adv.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Animation = " + chk_Anim.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Comedy = " + chk_Com.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Crime = " + chk_Crime.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Documentary = " + chk_Doc.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Drama = " + chk_Drama.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Family = " + chk_Fam.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Games = " + chk_Game.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Mystery = " + chk_Mys.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND Romance = " + chk_Rom.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND SciFi = " + chk_Sci.Checked ? -1 : 0 +
" AND War = " + chk_War.Checked ? -1 : 0 + ";";

Fill_Grid(str_SQL);
```

**Update**
if you are using in ms-access and datatype is `Yes/No`, then true=-1 and false=0, [check here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp?output=print)

Comment: It's in an Access database so the type is bolean I'm guessing, since the flags are Y/N or T/F.

The above code did not work.  Thanks for the input Arshad